# load magento controller method from Template

Tags: template

I have two simple method inside controller

```
<?php   
public indexAction 
{}
public TestAction{

echo "Kkkdfd"
}
```

I have a template named something.phtml 
How do i call testaction from my template to display php echo?

Answer (score 1):

You don't, controllers aren't meant for that. You can call module/controller/action as url to display the echo. If you want to use a custom method to handle some logic in your template use blocks instead.

Edit:
I can't help you with the library, but to finish up this answer I give you an example to create a custom block.

Create a new module in `app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create a module config `app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <your_module>
                <class>Your_Module_Block</class>
            </your_module>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

The global/blocks part defines your Block Prefix, which you can use to call it in your layout.

Create the block now in `app/code/local/Your/Module/Block/Block.php`

```
class Your_Module_Block_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function yourLogic() 
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is change your layout block to use the new custom block. Do it like this:

```
<block type="your_module/block" name="yourblock" template="your/template.phtml" />
```

The type refers to your `config.xml` and block file. `The your_module` part is the block prefix, so `Your_Module_Block`, and the second `block` part refers to the Block.php file.

In your template you can make a direct call to `$this->yourLogic()` now.

Hope this helps your sort things out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use block to load those? thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you just using some custom template or do you want to modify an existing one? The difference is a new block or overriding an existing one, which both work a bit differently.

Comment: its custom template. Actually i am trying to get third party php library to work but i cant seem to get to autoloader. so i decided to use template to call the controller for event and then make an observer to autoload the lib. if you have any idea about abrahim/twitterauto, please let me know.

Comment: See my edited answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

from your comments I read that your actual problem is that the library is not loaded.

The easiest way would be to install it with composer and use magento module that includes the composer autoloader.

If you don't know how to install / use composer, you should start here:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

once composer is working you can install your library with the following command:

composer require abrahim/twitterauto

The Problem now is, that Magento does not include the Composer Autoloader, but there is a Module for this:
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader